# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I want to store result of total & tempDiscRs into b1..while storing it throws the error that Input string was not in correct format

```
decimal b1 = Convert.ToDecimal(lblDisRate.Text);
b1 = total * tempDiscRs;
```

Comment: What is the value ot `lblDisRate.Text`?

Comment: you can try decimal.TryParse(lblDisRate.Text); if it is in a deciamal format everything is going to be ok but otherwise it will throw an exception

Comment: Make sure the value in `lblDisRate.Text` is numeric.

Comment: total=673
txtdiscount.text=23
a1=23

Comment: Actually  i am storing value of total  & tempDiscRs into lbldisRate..but lbldisRate is string value so I am firstly converting lbldisRate into decimal and later storing value of total  & tempDiscRsin it

Comment: I got the solution ...I stored result of total & tempDiscRs into temporary variable & later assigned it to  lblDisRate.Text & it works :):)

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal myValue;
if(Decimal.TryParse(lblDisRate.Text, out myValue))
{
   //correct
}
else
{
   //wrong
}
```

See more about [Decimal.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the culture you're in.

Example: In US, the comma separator is a dot (.) while in Germany it is a comma (,).

Try

```
lblDisRate.Text.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

In order to use Invariant Culture so you always use a dot instead of a comma.